# Is there a chance to use a custom std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator to make std::unordered_map’s buckets implemented as arrays?

Tags: c++, stl, allocation, unordered-map

While liked-list buckets implementation in `std::unordered_map` works well when one needs to add/remove elements from the container, it still could be speed up significantly if “stable” or “read-only” version utilizes arrays for buckets. This could help in cases the `std::unordered_map` filled one time and then used only for lookups.

Can `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` help in changing the used strategy from linked list to array? If so, could you, please, give a clue how this could be done?

If not, what is the best way to achieve the goal above without implementing such a container from scratch?

Comment: use C++23 [flat_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/flat_map) instead when it is finally implemented by the compilers, it is in boost and google template libraries for older cpp versions, along with hashed versions.

Comment: AFAIK the way the standard mandates the behavior of the buckets and the interface makes it required to use a linked list to be conformant.  I can't recall the exact chain of logic.  Might have been in a Chandler Carruth talk at cppcon.

Comment: @AhmedAEK, `std::flat_map` is a container adapter that handles sorted elements. Thus, it gives the functionality of an associative container, like `std::map`, not an unordered associative container, like `std::unordered_map`.

Comment: Allocators, including `std::pmr:::polymorphic_allocator`, can not change the underlying implementation, but they can be used to handle differently the memory allocation. A performance improvement in node-based containers, like `std::unordered_map`, might be obtained by using a pool allocator, which may significantly reduce memory fragmentation and increase cache locality if adjacent elements are allocated sequentially.

Comment: This one is outstanding: https://isocpp.org/blog/2017/03/i-wrote-the-fastest-hashtable-malte-skarupke